# Can't update Visual Studio 2019 due to ssl certificate issue

Tags: visual-studio

When I open vs installer to install updates, it asks to update installer first and then fails to download packages. I'm getting "Unable to download installation files. Check your internet connection and try again" error.

I tried to capture installer's requests with fiddler and it looks like it can't establish connection to https://aka.ms because of expired/wrong root certificate on my computer.

And I can't open aka.ms in browser, getting ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, which IMO proves that this is the issue.

I have latest windows version (20H2), no new updates in updates center.

How can I install new certificate to be able to connect to aka.ms? Where can I get it?

Comment: Did you try disabling your antivirus?

Comment: Agree with @41686d6564. Also are your trying to update on your own computer or on your employer computer? Some companies' policies can deny using some of the root certs. Also if you are living in some contries like Russia, Turkey, China, etc some IPs are banned by regulators, try to use proxies or VPNs.

Comment: I have only Windows Defender, I don't think it would do that, but I'll try.
@otter, it's my own computer

Comment: As expected, turning off windows firewall and real-time protection in Windows Defender settings didn't help

Comment: Interesting. I was able to download `vs_installer.opc` from `https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/installer` using FriGate proxy. Usually this is indeed a problem with address ban by regulators (I live in Russia), but I've never seen ssl errors in such cases. Another explanation - proxy server simply has the required root cert and this helps. But this isn't a solution - I still need this certificate on my computer for installer to download this file and probably all update packages.

Comment: Ok, I installed Windscribe VPN and was able to update installer with VPN turned on and Visual Studio itself without VPN. That's great! But I still can't access aka.ms without proxy/VPN and that sucks. I hope it will be fixed somehow (mb windows update) later, or if it's really a regulator's ban, it will be unbanned (no idea, how - this address and its' IP isn't in regulator's public blacklist, I checked). In any case, thanks for help! @otter, I think, you should post your comment as answer for me being able to mark it as correct one

Comment: @Lucky Actually I also live in Russia and used to have troubles when using vcpkg, Win update, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you live in contries with strict Internet regulations (like Russia, China, Turkey) you should try using VPNs or proxies.

Regulators make ISPs to block some IPs/URLs. And some ISPs display their own stub webpages instead of the original web content. These stub pages usually says that you are not allowed to look at "restricted content". When using SSL/HTTPS some ISPs also try to response to your queries which can result in certificate errors.

Also it can turn out that some several IPs from MS IP addresses pool are blocked. And some MS functionality stop working.